# Styling text object within a function

Tags: javascript

I am using the below script function on bootstrap tabs, I am trying to add styling to the last line to style the `text: 'Other Sections'` part of the code, I have been looking around but have found nothing that works.

```
if(top.location != location){
    top.location.href = document.location.href;
}
$(function(){
    window.prettyPrint && prettyPrint();
    $('.nav-tabs:first').tabdrop();
    $('.nav-pills').tabdrop({text: 'Other Sections'});
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to acheive? What have you tried?

Comment: Please clarify, its not clear what you want to do

Comment: The line of code in question inserts another tab when the window is re-sized, the text on this tab is currently a dark blue, and want to add a lighter colour.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply inject HTML markup in the `text` property, no other hacking is neccessary.

For example you can make it italic by using:

```
$('.nav-pills').tabdrop({
    text: '<i>Other Sections</i>'}
);
```

**Edit:** (added an example code based on the question)

```
<style>
    .myTabDrop {
        color: blue;
    }
    .myTabDrop:hover {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
if(top.location != location){
    top.location.href = document.location.href;
}
$(function(){
    window.prettyPrint && prettyPrint();
    $('.nav-tabs:first').tabdrop();
    $('.nav-pills').tabdrop({text: '<span class="myTabDrop">Other Sections</span>'});
    $('.nav-pills .caret').attr('class', 'myTabDrop');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I follow what you mean but how escapes me just now, could you post the line with the addition thanks.

Comment: added a very simple example, in a more complex case, you might inject a tag into it (e.g. a `span`) with an id, and spit a whole DOM subtree into it. (Not that I would recommend it :) )

Comment: How would I add a colour?

Comment: `<span style="color: blue;">Other Section</span>`, but you should use classes instead

Comment: Thanks that worked the text is now the colour I wanted, however with this tab being a dropdown to it's right side there is a down pointing arrow, this is still the dark blue, how would I add colour to that too?

Also you said about classes how would the line be made up if I used them?

I also need to add a a.hover colour.

Comment: That colour is controlled by the CSS of Bootstrap.If you need to change it only there, you can create a selector for, and apply the style attribute, e.g. `$('.nav-pills .caret').attr('style', 'color: blue;');` But instead of hacking, I suggest customizing Bootstrap instead.

Comment: Sorry for posting here but I am new and it will not let me move this discussion to chat yet.

Thanks for all the input so far it has helped a lot, I now just need to add a hover colour to the text, how would that be done?

Comment: If you need to use hover too, I'd definetely use a class instead, eg. `.myclass { color: blue } .myclass:hover { color: red }` and use that class: `$('.nav-pills .caret').attr('class', 'myclass');`

Comment: Thanks for the reply meskobalazs, I am ok with normal CSS but I am having a problem when it comes to adding the coding into my function, could you add that to my above script function so that I can get the idea as to how it works thanks.

Comment: Thanks it's nearly there now, on a full screen window the tabs text colour changes from yellow to blue when a white background shows on hover, the tabdrop gets this white hover but the text only changes to yellow if the mouse pointer is on it, I want it like the other tabs, also the down point arrow is not now showing.